# gt colors based on value

Tags: r, colors, gt

Is there a cleaner way to achieve this ?

To do coloring based on a hex in a column.

```r
library(gt)
library(dplyr)
cols <- tibble::tibble(
  color = c(
    "dark navy blue", "true black", "light blue", "teal", "gold", "burnt orange",
    "green", "burgundy", "bright turquoise", "purple"
  ),
  hex = c(
    "#1D4E79", "#000000", "#70BBC3", "#3F8F97", "#FAC61E", "#C36627", "#8BC167",
    "#820000", "#33CCCC", "#CC33CC"
  ),
)
cols |> gt::gt() |> gt::data_color(fn = function(x) cols$hex)
```

[image]